# is there a way to do generic code with macro setting in language C?

Tags: c, macros, generic-programming

I have a code who manages a lot of different products.
Variables and their characteristics are set by X macro.

5 functions(of 10) by product that have the same process with different prefix and different macro.

i would like to put these functions as generic.

*file product_1.c*

```
void product_1_init(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_A;
  PRODUCT1_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
  PRODUCT1_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}

void product_1_format_data_uart(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_B;
  PRODUCT1_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}
...
```

*file product_2.c*

```
void product_2_init(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_A;
  PRODUCT2_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
  PRODUCT2_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}

void product_2_format_data_uart(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_B;
  PRODUCT2_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}
...
```

I would like know if is it possible of doing something like this:

*file product_generic.c*

```
#define PRODUCT_FUNC(name) PRODUCT_FUNC_(PRODUCT_GEN_NAME, name)
#define PRODUCT_FUNC_(prefix, name)  PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name)
#define PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name) prefix ## name

void PRODUCT_FUNC(_init)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_A;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}

void PRODUCT_FUNC(_format_data_uart)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_B;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}
...
//put here every function with process in commun to every product
```

*file product_1.c*

```
#define PRODUCT_GEN_NAME product_1
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA PRODUCT1_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA PRODUCT1_XMACRO_UART_DATA

#include "product_generic.c"  /*doesn't work*/

#undef PRODUCT_GEN_NAME
#undef PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
#undef PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
```

*file product_2.c*

```
#define PRODUCT_GEN_NAME product_2
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA PRODUCT2_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA PRODUCT2_XMACRO_UART_DATA

#include "product_generic.c" /*doesn't work*/

#undef PRODUCT_GEN_NAME
#undef PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
#undef PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
```

my main probleme is how "#include product_generic.c" in my different product file.

the compilateur dosen't want include '.c' file and we can't put function in '.h' file.

Comment: Your question is missing the problem. Now answers have to guess what it is (and already have). Please [edit] and add a clear problem description: *What is it that is wrong with your current approach?*

Answer (score 3):

The macro substitution for `PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA` should work, but `void PRODUCT_GEN_NAME ## _init(void* p_generic_ptr)` does not.

You can use `##` only inside a preprocessor macro and at least one of the parts to be concatenated must be a macro argument.

_file product_generic.c_

```
/* add fixed PRODUCT_GEN_NAME as prefix */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC(name) PRODUCT_FUNC_(PRODUCT_GEN_NAME, name)
/* next macro call necessary to get PRODUCT_GEN_NAME expanded before ## */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC_(prefix, name)  PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name)
/* and finally concatenate the parts */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name) prefix ## name

/* you could also use the second macro here */
/* void PRODUCT_FUNC_(PRODUCT_GEN_NAME,_init)(void* p_generic_ptr) */
void PRODUCT_FUNC(_init)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_A;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}

void PRODUCT_FUNC(_format_data_uart)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_B;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}
...
//put here every function with process in commun to every product
```

Proposed solution for the second problem that was added to the question

If you are neither allowed to include a C file nor to define functions in header files, you could use a single file `product_generic.c` that contains `#include "product_definitions.h"` and use product specific include files with the same name but in different locations

```
product_1/product_definitions.h
product_2/product_definitions.h
...
```

combined with product specific compilation commands using different include directories and different output files. Something like this

```
cc -I product_1 product_generic.c -o product_1.c
cc -I product_2 product_generic.c -o product_2.c
...
```

_file product_generic.c_

```
#include "product_definitions.h"

/* add fixed PRODUCT_GEN_NAME as prefix */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC(name) PRODUCT_FUNC_(PRODUCT_GEN_NAME, name)
/* next macro call necessary to get PRODUCT_GEN_NAME expanded before ## */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC_(prefix, name)  PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name)
/* and finally concatenate the parts */
#define PRODUCT_FUNC__(prefix, name) prefix ## name

void PRODUCT_FUNC(_init)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_A;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}

void PRODUCT_FUNC(_format_data_uart)(void* p_generic_ptr)
{
#define DATA(v1,...,v20) PROCESS_B;
  PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA
#undef DATA
}
...
//put here every function with process in commun to every product
```

_file product_1/product_definitions.h_

```
#define PRODUCT_GEN_NAME product_1
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA PRODUCT1_XMACRO_LOCAL_DATA
#define PRODUCT_GEN_XMACRO_UART_DATA PRODUCT1_XMACRO_UART_DATA
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I corrected this problem.

Comment: @Bodo: Why do you say one of the operands of `##` must be a macro argument? The example in C 2018 6.10.3.3 4 shows a case where this is not so, `#define hash_hash # ## #`.